# Excel document created using powershell and EPPlus does not open in SSIS package

Tags: powershell, ssis, epplus

I am a newbie to PowerShell and would appreciate some help with PowerShell and EPPlus.

I needed to be able to NOT install excel on the servers and came across this fabulous tool and it works a treat, BUT when I use the workbook created using the EPPlus library in SSIS Connection Source, the source task does not recognise the excel workbook format of xlsx. I have also tried xls as well.

How do I save it in the correct excel format using PowerShell and the EPPlus library?

Just a note if I open the excel workbook, click save and close I can then see the sheets in the SSIS Connection Source. It is like it does not know what format the file is when using the EPPlus library to save the file.

This is the code I am using, please bear with as I am very new to this.

```
# Load EPPlus
$DLLPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\EPPlus\EPPlus.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($DLLPath) | Out-Null

$SourceFile = 'c:\Temp\Demo.xlsx'
$Password = '654645231'
$DestinationFile = 'C:\Temp\NBNoPassword.xlsx'

$NoPassword = ""

# Open Excel File with Password
$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage -ArgumentList $SourceFile,$password

$ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets
$ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy("Sheet1","Product") 
$ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy("Sheet2","Test") 
$ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete("Sheet1")
$ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete("Sheet2")

#Save Excel File
$ExcelPackage.Save As($DestinationFile,$NoPassword) 

$ExcelPackage.Workbook.Dispose()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards
Angie